# How can write a clean url in php?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

How can write a clean url  from http://domain.com/details.php?users=53#People to http://domain.com/53#people/ 
work out i need help fellows

Comment: This question can be easily answered with a quick search, both in Google and here. Also, the "clean" url you posted as example, isn't a valid url.

Comment: Hey i have tried out already, i just cant what i want, if you know the answer please just tell me instead of referring me to the huge Google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really asking is that the request to details.php gets routed to index.php.

You will therefore need some code in index.php to understand this request is for details.

You can use this in your *.htaccess* file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

In your *index.php*, you can extract the actual request and action it.

```
$request = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], strlen('/index.php'));
```